# Python Chatterbot problems with learn_response function

Tags: python, discord.py, chatterbot

I'am coding a Discord Bot that uses ChatterBot to interact.

I want to create a command that makes the bot learn an input via chat.

```
@client.command(aliases=['tc'])
async def treinocustom(ctx, response, input_statement):
    chatbot.learn_response(response, input_statement)
    ctx.send('Thanks for the feedback')
```

But when i execute the command this error shows on the console:

```
Ignoring exception in command treinocustom:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\envbom\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/SamuelBot/SamuelBot.py", line 227, in treinocustom
    chatbot.learn_response(arg1, arg2)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\envbom\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 225, in learn_response
    statement.in_response_to = previous_statement
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'in_response_to'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\envbom\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\envbom\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\envbom\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'in_response_to'
```

What can i do to fix it?

Comment: i'm not familiar with the library you are using, but it seems like this is a type error. It seems like you have passed a string to a library function that expects a statement object (or at least an object that has the `in_response_to` attribute). Perhaps check the documentation for `learn_response` to see what arguments it expects.

Comment: @truculence The function says:
`def learn_response(self, statement, previous_statement=None):`

Comment: since python has a pretty weak typing system, the function signature alone doesn't go very far in terms of determining how to proceed with type/interface errors. If you look up the library documentation, it _probably_ has a more detailed explanation of how to use the function, or sample code. If that is unfruitful, maybe search the documentation or the source code for a Statement class?

Comment: @truculence [link](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/chatterbot.html?highlight=learn_response#chatterbot.ChatBot.learn_response) the official site only shows that the function exists and requires `(statement, previous_statement)` and the only class is `class ChatBot(object)`

Comment: maybe this will help [link](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/conversations.html#chatterbot.conversation.Statement)

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem here is that the chatterbot function `learn_response()` does NOT take strings as arguments, but a special datatype (local to chatterbot) called a `Statement`. So, to get your response in this datatype, you have to first import it by:

`from chatterbot.conversation import Statement`

on the top of your code. Second, just make these changes to your `treinocustom()` function:

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["tc"])
async def treinocustom(ctx, *, parts):
    if parts.count(">") == 1:
        Question, Answer= [i.strip() for i in parts.split('>')]
        #here, we are changing the strings 'Question' and 'Answer' to a Statment datatype.
        input_statement = Statement(text=Question) 
        correct_response = Statement(text=Answer)
        chatbot.learn_response(correct_response, input_statement)
        await ctx.send("Ok, I have learnt the correct response to this query!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Please enter only two arguments!")
```

So, what I noticed in your code is that the `response` and `input_statement` arguments will only take **one word** as input, but we actually need sentences as input.

In this function above, though, the user can give the command like so:

`[bot_prefix] tc what is your name? > My name is ChatterBot!`

Second of all, I converted the `Question` and `Answer` strings to `Statement`s, which the learn_response() function recognises.

Third of all, the command will work even if the user inputs how many ever space bars before and after the ">" in other words, even

`[bot_prefix] tc what is your name?       >        My name is ChatterBot!`

will work perfectly! that is due to the `strip()` function used...

I had faced the same issue as you, but after digging through the the githup repo of chatterbot, I found some very good example codes, and found out the correct usage of the function from them. I you are interested, you can find the `learn_response()` example code [here](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/master/examples/learning_feedback_example.py).